# How to play m3u8 file in flutter. | Exoplayer 403 user_agent rejection error

Tags: flutter, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

I am new on flutter. I am trying to integrate video player in my app which can play `m3u8` video but only some file can play when they only exoplayer user_agent.

and when I shift to webview than it's dropping frames please help me to find the answer.

I used `chewie_player` , `video_player` , `loco_player` to make it work but none of them works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Play m3u8 file using `chewie: ^1.4.0`.
[Go to package](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)

chewie package supports both Android and iOS platforms. This package provides a video player widget based on ExoPlayer.

- Install `chewie` to your flutter project

  ```
   flutter pub add chewie
  ```
- example Code:

  ```
  class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
  }

  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'url.m3u8');
    ChewieController chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample App"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Chewie(controller: chewieController),
        ));
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your response,
Although it doesn't the problem yet. I tried to use it but it still give an error
"com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403"
Please use this url as a demo https://wwwx17.gofcdn.com/videos/hls/A7DVIdr74YFUnNYjYgJw9A/1676490339/88386/395c00c8e81e269aa76202288b5c4727/ep.2.1660628444.m3u8